# EasyPhP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, easyphp

I am trying to setup a MySql Database using EasyPhP.
I know that it is installed along with other, packages, and i checked that my mySQL database is running.
in my C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.5.0\mysql\data, i have 2 folders.
"mysql" and "phpmyadmin", and some other files. those 2 folders are supposed to be databases right??
how do i create a simple database, so i can exercise my php, and mysql?
thx.

Answer (score 5):

You databases are stored in the MySQL folder inside of the EasyPHP folder. If you want to create a database, start EasyPHP, right click on the icon on the bottom right of your screen in your task bar (it's a black E), and click "Administration CTRL+A". This will load up the administration page. On the left side, around the middle of the page you will see a link that says "Manage MySQL with PhpMyAdmin". Click that and that will load up phpMyAdmin.

phpMyAdmin will be your database administration tool. Simply fill in the text field that says "Create new database" and hit "Create" and it will set up an empty database for you. You will have to add in the actual tables and data though.

Answer (score 1):

ou databases are stored in the MySQL folder inside of the EasyPHP folder. If you want to create a database, start EasyPHP, right click on the icon on the bottom right of your screen in your task bar (it's a black E), and click `Administration CTRL+A`. This will load up the administration page. On the left side, around the middle of the page you will see a link that says `Manage MySQL with PhpMyAdmin`. Click that and that will load up phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the database files in `/binaries/mysql/data/`

```
#Path to the database root
datadir = "${path}/binaries/mysql/data/"
```